# SQL BigQuery Resources Exceeded doing a LEFT JOIN with a large table (100 Million rows) What should I do to have a good performance/optimization?

Tags: sql, performance, google-bigquery, query-optimization

I want to retrieve the information from my **client table** (100 million rows) with my **campaigns table** (2000 rows). I've been using the campaigns table as the **LEFT table** because I want all the data from there (I know that `COUNT(DISTINCT)` doesn't help with a good performance but I don't know another clause than DISTINCT).

I've been using this query:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT
    CASE
     WHEN CLIENT.date <= CAMP.end_date AND CLIENT.date >= CAMP.start_date AND CLIENT.freq <= 1 THEN client_id
END
) AS new_client,

FROM CAMP
 LEFT JOIN CLIENT
 ON CAMP.country=CLIENT.country
```

| Rows | new_clients |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6543210 |

This single query took me 23 min to retrieve the data. And this is just a piece of the query that I really want to use (in the next query I have the error "resourcesExceeded 400"). I'm not using a `WHERE` clause because I need all the clients. To see if they are new or old clients.

The query that I really want to use is this one:

```
SELECT 

 COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN CLIENT.date <= CAMP.end_date AND CLIENT.date >= CAMP.start_date  AND CLIENT.freq <= 1 THEN client_id  END) AS new_client,

COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN CLIENT.date <= CAMP.end_date AND CLIENT.date >= CAMP.start_date  AND CLIENT.freq > 1 THEN client_id  END) AS old_client,

COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN CLIENT.date <= CAMP.end_date AND CLIENT.date >= CAMP.start_date AND CLIENT.country IN ("USA","EUROPA","MEXICO","OCEANIA","ASIA") AND  freq = 1 THEN client_id END ) + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN CLIENT.date <= CAMP.end_date AND CLIENT.date >= CAMP.start_date AND CLIENT.country NOT IN ("USA","EUROPA","MEXICO","OCEANIA","ASIA") AND  year_freq >= 1 AND  year_freq <= 3 THEN client_id END ) AS low_activity,

COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN CLIENT.date <= CAMP.end_date AND CLIENT.date >= CAMP.start_date AND CLIENT.country IN ("USA","EUROPA","MEXICO","OCEANIA","ASIA") AND  freq = 2 THEN client_id END ) + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN CLIENT.date <= CAMP.end_date AND CLIENT.date >= CAMP.start_date AND CLIENT.country NOT IN ("USA","EUROPA","MEXICO","OCEANIA","ASIA") AND  year_freq > 3 AND  year_freq <= 6 THEN client_id END ) AS medium_activity,

COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN CLIENT.date <= CAMP.end_date AND CLIENT.date >= CAMP.start_date AND CLIENT.country IN ("USA","EUROPA","MEXICO","OCEANIA","ASIA") AND  freq >= 3 THEN client_id END ) + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN CLIENT.date <= CAMP.end_date AND CLIENT.date >= CAMP.start_date AND CLIENT.country NOT IN ("USA","EUROPA","MEXICO","OCEANIA","ASIA") AND  year_freq > 6 THEN client_id END ) AS high_activity,

FROM CAMP
LEFT JOIN CLIENT
ON CAMP.country = CLIENT.country
```

This query runs 1 hour and then it breaks with the error "resources exceeded". So I'm asking to you if there is another way to improve the query.

What I want is to have the share of new and old clients from the weeks that I do special campaigns and within the old clients the **medium_activity** client and the **high_activity** client. new_client would be **low_activity**.

I'm 99% sure that this query crashes because of too many `COUNT(DISTINCT)`. As being a noob in SQL I don't know how to optimize this query. If there is something better than `COUNT(DISTINCT)` it would be cool to know.

The client table is not using any partition

Any suggestion, opinion, help, new clause, new statement, etc. to improve the performance/optimization of this query is very welcome.

Comment: Can you explain what the query is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Do your client table partition or cluster?

Comment: @KaBoom Neither

Comment: @GordonLinoff It should retrieve the share of new and old clients. also the frequency of the clients if they like to buy the product (low, medium and high frequency of buying). All of this in different periods of time when we are doing special campaigns.